# Asp.net split / test text content

Tags: asp.net

For me this task can be done easily with javascript by `indexOf() > -1`, but I don't really know how to start my coding with asp.net. I got some URLs look like below

```
www.google.com/this/that/new/this-url/bad
www.google.com/this/that/new/this-url/good
www.google.com/this/that/this-url/useless
```

I'd like to test if the url contents `/this-url/` if yes, then remove from `/this-url/` and rest
so the output is

```
www.google.com/this/that/new/
www.google.com/this/that/new/
www.google.com/this/that/
```

if someone could help me out please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the same way.

```
string s = "whatever/this/is";
int i = s.IndexOf("this");

if (i > -1) 
{
    string s2 = s.Substring(0, i - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following code in C#, use this in Asp.net in your own way.

Firstly add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` in `Namespace`

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = "www.google.com/this/that/new/this-url/bad";
        Console.WriteLine(str);

        string substr = "/this-url/";
        if (str.IndexOf(substr) == -1) {
            Console.WriteLine("No Match Found : ");
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
        else {
            string[] newstr = Regex.Split(str,substr);
            Console.WriteLine(newstr[0]);                
        }
    }
}
```

On execution i got following result :-

```
www.google.com/this/that/new/this-url/bad
www.google.com/this/that/new
```

Comment: @olo : Just use the logic don't go for `Console.WriteLine()` thing.

Comment: this only removes the search string, it doesn't truncate from its first instance.  See my answer.

Comment: @intracept : Thanks for information, i have edited the code again hope this works out for **olo** :)

Comment: If you use Split you don't need to do any additional pre-checks as if the search term doesn't exist you will be returned the entire string in the first element in the array :)